# Java Object taking variables from another instance?

Tags: java, oop, variables

I'm not quite sure what to call it, but essentially, when I run this code:

```
public class test {

    static Device one;
    static Device two;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        one = new Device("One", "ONE");
        System.out.println(one.getName());
        two = new Device("Two", "TWO");

        System.out.println(one.getName());
        System.out.println(two.getName());

    }
}
```

The output is:

```
ONE  
TWO
TWO
```

when it should be:

```
ONE
ONE
TWO
```

The device object is pretty simple, it just receives two strings, the second being the "name" that I'm asking it to print. I've done OOP before, but I feel like I'm just forgetting some important aspect, but can't seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

And here is the device constructor:

```
public Device(String iP, String Name) {
    //Set the IP address
    IP = iP;
    //Set the device's name
    name = Name;
    // Set the string version of the device (for transmitting)
    stringVersion = IP + ";" + name;
}
```

Comment: If you could print the Device constructor, it would help us answer.

Comment: Show the whole Device class. Are IP and Name static?

Comment: Yes, they are, thank you so much. Man I forgot about that... Thanks again!

Comment: You should be able to implement this without any `static` fields. I suggest you use local variables and final non-static fields where possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you've used `static` fields in `Device` too. These are not instance fields. Mutable `static` fields should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> Show the whole Device class. Are IP and Name static? – assylias 2 mins
>   ago
>
> Yes, they are

Your device static members get reinitialized whenever you instantiate a new instance of `Device` that's why you get that behavior. You can have `one` and `two` as `static` but you shouldn't have mutable member variables `static`